# How do you initialize/add/remove items from Fuel UX SelectList with javascript (not canned html)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, fuelux

I'm also using knockout.js, so if possible, I would like to use knockout binding, though I can work around that if there is a way to add/remove items from the dropdown list via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'd do it however you'd add items to a normal Bootstrap Dropdown which I believe is just appending `<a>`'s. As long as your `<a>`'s `click` event gets fired and thus `this.itemClicked` runs--I don't think it should matter. See [this line in selectlist.js](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/master/js/selectlist.js#L39).

And you might not want to use the auto resize feature either. It's a little buggy right now.